# How can I create a class that "proxy" an object?

Tags: typescript

I want to create a class that behaves exactly like another class. But the object have to be already instantiated so I can't use heritage:

```
class Welcomer {
    sayHello () {
        console.log('Hello World')
    }
}

class Foo {
    private welcomer;

    constructor (welcomer: Welcomer) {
        this.welcomer = welcomer;
    }

    sayHello () {
        this.welcomer.sayHello();
    }
}
```

Basically, I want my `Foo` class to have every methods of the `Welcomer` class. And the methods on the `Foo` class should only call methods on the `Welcomer` class.

How can I do that without rewriting all the methods in the `Foo` class?

Comment: So you want to do this dynamically, without knowing what methods are in your class being proxied, and without writing the proxy class yourself?

Comment: I would say, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Proxy` class in ES2015 to intercept get/set calls and wrap the function and call the proxied implementation:

```
class Welcomer {
    sayHello() {
        console.log('Hello World')
    }
}

var welcomer = new Welcomer();
var proxy = new Proxy(welcomer, {
    get(target, prop) {

        var value = target[prop as keyof Welcomer];
        if(typeof value === 'function'){
            return function() {
                console.log(`Calling ${prop.toString()}`);
                value.apply(target, arguments);
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
})


proxy.sayHello()
proxy.foo() // error
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Welcomer%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20sayHello()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('Hello%20World')%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20welcomer%20%3D%20new%20Welcomer()%3B%0D%0Avar%20proxy%20%3D%20new%20Proxy(welcomer%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20get(target%2C%20prop)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20value%20%3D%20target%5Bprop%20as%20keyof%20Welcomer%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if(typeof%20value%20%3D%3D%3D%20'function')%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20function()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%60Calling%20%24%7Bprop.toString()%7D%60)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value.apply(target%2C%20arguments)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0Aproxy.sayHello()%0D%0A%2F%2Fproxy.foo()%20%2F%2F%20error)

Comment: This was too easy for you, Titian :-) BTW this is correct of course

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev I am a simple person, I see a question, I know an answer, I write a post :) But I will admit it was low hanging fruit :P

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response but I can't get your code to work, I don't know why: https://jsfiddle.net/c1ts609y/24/

Comment: Works as expected in the playground, added a link to it in the answer.